# NS-3 WIFI Base Station and accesspoint handover

Tags: ns-3

I am a new user of NS-3. Can you help me in writing a code of handover in between nodes in Wi-Fi environment?

Comment: perhaps you should show some effort? your Bio states you are a Phd student: I'd expect more from you than the total lack of effort shown.

Comment: Yup i have some effort and here I am asking for help that means I need urgently so I am searching for expert who can help me very early.

Comment: " I need urgently"  - that's nice for you, but you still have shown ZERO effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna base my response on the little information you have provided.

General idea of Wi-Fi (as the technology which we use on daily basis to connect to internet and stuff like that :D) is based on IEEE 802.11 standard which does not support handover between nodes. Therefor you either are asking the wrong question or you want to implement the handover support to a IEEE 802.11 standard.

In case you want to do the latter I strongly suggest you to do the following steps ([NS-3 tutorial in case needed](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/)):

1- Install NS-3 simulator on a Linux operating system, preferably Ubuntu 14.04.

2- Browse wifi/examples folder and try to fully understand basic wifi examples.

3- Implement your proposed algorithm in proposed scenario (Which obviously requires you to understand how user equipment connects to a Wi-Fi access point automatically and how APs can interact with each other and etc.).